# Setting permissions to broadcast messages across multiple desktops

Tags: c++, winapi, privileges, message

Hi,

I'm trying to send messages between applications that are located on different desktops. In order to accomplish this, I'm using [BroadCastSystemMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644932(v=vs.85).aspx) using `BSM_ALLDESKTOPS` set for `LPDWORD lpdwRecipients` parameter.

As the MSDN documentation says, `BSM_ALLDESKTOPS` - *Broadcast to all desktops. Requires the SE_TCB_NAME privilege.*

In order to meet this requirement I've found the following example which generates the `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`, with the code `1300 - Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller`, in the last if statement:

```
BOOL GrantPrivilege::SetPrivilege(HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, lpszPrivilege, &luid))
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.
    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        &tp,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
        (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
        printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. %u\n ", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Maybe the error is caused by the way I'm making the call for this function:

```
HANDLE hToken;
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    printf("%u", GetLastError());
GrantPrivilege gPriv;
gPriv.SetPrivilege(hToken, L"SeTcbPrivilege", true);
```

**P.S.** I've tried runing this application from an elevated prompt, but the result is the same, `1300` error code.

Comment: There are no C++ classes in the Windows API. In other words: `GrantPrivilege` is not part of the Windows API. What is it? Where is the implementation for `GrantPrivilege::SetPrivilege`?

Comment: The winapi tag was added by Oswald. The implementation for `GrantPrivilege::SetPrivilege` is the one from   [Enabling and Disabling Privileges in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619(v=vs.85).aspx)  link from the post.

Comment: Questions and answers on Stackoverlow should be self-contained. The rationale behind this rule is, that they must not lose value when an external resource becomes unavailable at some point in the future. Please take the time to include all relevant information in your question.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I was unaware. I'm editing the question right now.

Comment: I think you've chosen the wrong IPC mechanism

Comment: I've used `BroadcastSystemMessage` and `GetMessage` to communicate between applications before, but they we're all in the same desktop. This is the first time trying to communicate between applications in different desktops. Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: A named pipe would make more sense here, for instance. In fact almost any IPC mechanism other than messages is what you need. However, you didn't ask that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error code means that current windows user is not allowed to use this privilege (this is why these are privileges, after all: not everyone have them). [It is possible to grant a user such privilege](http://memorybuffer.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/how-to-give-setcbprivilege-to-an-account/), but I **strongly** advise against it. Instead, you should use some other form of inter-process communication. If you only need a signal without data, named event should be good. Otherwise, it could be a named pipe, socket, or shared memory section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At least now I know how it's possible to grant this privilege. As for the application, I have succesefuly used named pipes as @David Heffernan suggested.